# how to show all examples of violation at prime check code

Tags: python

i write python code for check number prime or not but this code show on examples for not prime and i want show all examples but doesn't work
without break show all but in last line show is prime.

```
x=int(input('Enter your number to check: '))
if x>1:
    for prime in range(2,x):
        if x % prime == 0:
            print(x,"isn't prime :",prime,'*',x // prime)
    else:
        print(x,'is prime')
else:
    print(x,"isn't prime")
```

for example enter x 18 show in terminal:

- 18 isn't prime : 2 * 9
- 18 isn't prime : 3 * 6
- 18 isn't prime : 6 * 3
- 18 isn't prime : 9 * 2
- 18 is prime   [it is wrong because 18 isn't prime and i want dont show this]

Comment: Please, reformat your code.

Comment: Are you sure the innermost `else` clause is properly indented?

Comment: In the construction for/else, clause `else` executes every time after loop completion.

Comment: @ForceBru yeah becuase If below second `if`  all test items are displayed

Comment: @magma how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = int(input('Enter your number to check: '))
is_prime = True
for prime in range(2, x):
    if x % prime == 0:
        is_prime = False
        print(x, "isn't prime :", prime, '*', x // prime)
if is_prime:
    print(x, "is prime")
```

Comment: can you explain `is_prime = false` what is it? because i'm beginner

Comment: @kami ```is_prime``` is simply variable describing if ```x``` number is prime. As you might have hoticed, it's suite self explanatory :) At the beginning I assume that the number is prime and therefore there's the statement ```is_prime = True```. The variable's value is changed only if there's condition satisfied - in this case ```x``` value need to fall into the loop and need to give ```0``` result during modulo division. If the conditions are not met, ```is_prime``` value doesn't change and we know that ```x``` is prime